# OpenCV for Android examples

Tags: android, opencv

Can anyone provide some examples of how to use OpenCV for Android?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [OpenCV Android Samples](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidSamples) there ara many examples how to work with OpenCV on Android.

Answer (score 0):

This article shows a few steps to use OpenCV in Android, [How to use Android-OpenCV JNI API](http://ibuzzlog.blogspot.tw/2012/07/how-to-use-android-opencv-jni-api.html). I think it is a good start.FYI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that are very useful for me from Opencv integration mentioned in 1st link to  OpenCV android sample app

[1](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c): [Open integration for Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c)

[Android Sample using OpenCv](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c)